# Items object should have equal property

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "Adam",
      "age": 22
    },
    {
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "name": "Justin",
      "age": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

and schema:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.com/object1607582431.json",
  "title": "Root",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "result"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "result": {
      "$id": "#root/result",
      "title": "Result",
      "type": "array",
      "default": [],
      "items": {
        "$id": "#root/result/items",
        "title": "Items",
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "name"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "$id": "#root/result/items/name",
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "age": {
            "$id": "#root/result/items/age",
            "title": "Age",
            "type": "integer",
            "default": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here `age` is an optional property. I am struggling to apply a rule if an optional property is present in one object then it should present in all the objects in that collection. Is there any option available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a really good use case for the `if`/`then` construct that really can't be replicated by using a `oneOf` like a switch statement.  (Well done.)

You're going to want to add the `if`/`then` construct to the `results` property subschema.  If the `if` passes, then the `then` MUST also apply.

```
"result": {
  ...,
  "if": {
    "contains": { "required": [ "age" ] }    // 1
  },
  "then": {
    "items": { "required": [ "age" ] }       // 2
  }
}
```

1. If the the `result` object *contains* an item that has an `age` property,
2. Require *all* items to have an `age` property.

---

### Edit

Full schema:

```json
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.com/object1607582431.json",
  "title": "Root",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "result"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "result": {
      "$id": "#root/result",
      "title": "Result",
      "type": "array",
      "default": [],
      "if": { "contains": { "required": [ "age" ] } },
      "then": { "items": { "required": [ "age" ] } },
      "items": {
        "$id": "#root/result/items",
        "title": "Items",
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "name"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "$id": "#root/result/items/name",
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "",
            "pattern": "^.*$"
          },
          "age": {
            "$id": "#root/result/items/age",
            "title": "Age",
            "type": "integer",
            "default": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instance:

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "one"
    },
    {
      "name": "two",
      "age": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "three"
    }
  ]
}
```

Remove the `age` property or add it to the other items to get the schema to pass.

Comment: I tested at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ and it seems not working. Can you please post full schema?

Comment: I would really suggest using https://jsonschema.dev/ instead.  It was made by @relequestual, who's heading up the JSON Schema spec (I'm on the team, too, and also have two validators for .Net).  I'll update the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233788/unique-value-for-a-property-validation-using-json-schema