# Unique value for a property validation using json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON object like:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name" : "abc",
      "email": "abc.test@mail.com"
      
    },
    {
      "name": "def",
      "email": "def.test@mail.com"
     
    },
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "email": "abc.test@mail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

and schema for this:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.com/object1607582431.json",
  "title": "Root",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "result"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "result": {
      "$id": "#root/result",
      "title": "Result",
      "type": "array",
      "default": [],
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "$id": "#root/result/items",
        "title": "Items",
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "name",
          "email"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "$id": "#root/result/items/name",
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "string"
           
          },
          "email": {
            "$id": "#root/result/items/email",
            "title": "Email",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am looking for an option to check uniqueness for `email` irrespective of name. How I can validate that every `email` should be unique?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There are no keywords that let you compare one particular data value against another, other than `uniqueItems`, which compares an array element *in toto* against another.

Answer (score 0):

The JsonSchema specification does not currently support this.
You can see the active GitHub issue here: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-vocabularies/issues/22

However, there are various extensions of JsonSchema that do validate unique fields within lists of objects.

If you happen to be using Python you can use the package (I created) JsonVL. It can be installed with `pip install jsonvl` and then run with `jsonvl data.json schema.json`.

Code examples in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/gregorybchris/jsonvl